# Strange typing issues Windows 11

Tags: windows, keyboard, typing

I've recently upgraded Windows 10 to Windows 11 on my desktop, but the problem I'm going to describe did not occur until a couple of days ago some time after upgrade. My system is fully updated.

Sticky and filter keys options are turned off, as well as fast boot. I've run keyboard troubleshoot for keyboard, performed scannow and DISM restore health. I have also reinstalled keyboard drivers. Problems occur regardless of keyboard and usb port or usb hub or usb wire.

1. I can't hold shift and and then type letters - only a couple of them are caps locked, the rest is small
2. On screen keyboard registers clicking Alt Gr as both alts, the same goes for shift and thus it triggers some strange shortcuts
3. I can't use ctrl+z or ctr+v unless each time I click both keys at the same time - if I hold ctrl and then type z or v, after a couple of clicks, I just type the letter. Keyboard State View registers does not register holding ctrl while I type z or v or whatever.

I want to troubleshoot the issues, because it's not normal to no to be able to type caps locked letters while holding shift or paste multiple times. Using alt triggers shortcuts in many applications which should not be triggered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Windows 11 has already gotten quite a few posts here. The simplest solution would perhaps be to roll back to Windows 10 (if the allowed 10 days have not passed yet).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot rollback to the previous version, since 10 days passed.

Comment: Try updating all your drivers to see if that helps. No typing issues here on two windows 11 machines.

Comment: "it's normal to no to be able to type caps locked letters while holding shift or paste multiple times" - I think you mean it's NOT normal.  Can you confirm?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should be it is not normal